# Hibernate query internal list

Tags: sql, hibernate, criteria

I have the following Hibernate entities:

```
@Entity
class A{
    String name;
}

@Entity
class B{
   List<A> aList;
}
```

I want to fetch all **B** from the database that **ALL** the names from a list are like the B's list for example, for the following list:

```
String lst[] = {"str1", "str2"};
```

I need to retrieve all B entries that has lists of two A's with the same strings as in the arrays.

I prefer using the Criteria queries but HQL or SQl are fine too.

Answer (score 0):

If your A and B entities are kept in A_table and B_table respectively, and the one to many relation ship from A to B is kept in A_table in the column b_id, then the corresponding SQL would be something like:

```
select distinct * from B_table join A_table on A_table.b_id=B_table .id where A_table.name="str1" or A_table.name="str2"
```

The HQL query would be something like:

```
select distinct b from B b inner join B.aList as a where a.name='str1' or a.nama='str2'
```